# Unable to load assembly exception in a library application consumed by a Windows service

Tags: .net, wcf, dll, config, microsoft-dynamics

I re-post here a question that I have already ask on the Dynamics community, but I guess I will not get any answer from their :

https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/171159

and I don't think knowledging in Dynamics is necessarily required to understand my problem.

I have a c# application in three parts :
- Windows service
- WPF view
- Shared library

(in the Dynamics forum post, it's a console application instead of a windows service, but the deal is the same)

The service application calls the method "Test()" of this class, which is in the library project :

```
public class Program
{
    private const string _connectionString = "[...]";
    private const long _channelId = 5637146827;

    public static void test()
    {
        var dllConfigPath = string.Concat(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "my_dll.config");

        var configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap()
        {
            ExeConfigFilename = dllConfigPath
        };

        var appConfigFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

        // configuration is successfully loaded at this point
        var configSection = (CommerceRuntimeSection)appConfigFile.GetSection("commerceRuntime");

        // an exception is throw here
        var commerceRuntimeConfiguration = new CommerceRuntimeConfiguration(configSection, _connectionString, true);

        var commercePrincipal = new CommercePrincipal(new CommerceIdentity(_channelId, Enumerable.Empty<string>()));

        var runtime = CommerceRuntime.Create(commerceRuntimeConfiguration, commercePrincipal);

        ChannelManager channelManager = ChannelManager.Create(runtime);
    }
}
```

**An exception "unable to load file or assembly Microsoft.Dynamics.Commerce.Runtime.Services" is thrown at the line
"new CommerceRuntimeConfiguration()"**

I don't have source code of this class, I just know it takes a section of config file in argument.
The config file is describe below, it's in the library project, not in the service project (it might be an important point).

http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/834895config.png (sry for this link, I fail to post the XML directly)

As I explain on the Dynamics forum, all the DLL required are properly includes in the library project.

I repost the same conclusion :

The only solution I have found, which is not acceptable from my point of view, is to :

- copy the .config file on the service windows application
- add all the dlls in the service windows application references. But I still need it in the library application (without, the code in the library doesn't compile) : so basically, I have to references twice all the DLLs...

**How can I make this application architecture works (without copy config and DLLs in the service) ?**

Thanks,

Charles

Comment: You have a library that requires  the my_dll.config and dynamics dll's.  Those files will have to be copied into folder with the services EXE somehow.  Could you explain why having to copy the files is not acceptable?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I may not be completely understandable earlier : I have no problem with the fact of copy (from the file properties) the my_dll.config in the destination folder. In fact, it's what I do (see below, the schema I want, and who seems OK for me, but who doesnt work).http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/292737configok.png What I don't want is to add the my_dll.config and all the DLLs BOTH in the service app and library app (which is the only way to makes things works so far...)